# Java thread question

Tags: java

I'm taking Java lessons. We're now into threads. It is the first time I'm experiencing multithreading so please excuse me if the question is very dumb :)

I've the following program:

```
public class Foo extends Thread {
    private int x = 2;

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        new Foo().fun();
    }

    Foo () {
        x = 5;
        start();
    }

    public void fun() {
        x = x - 1;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    public void run() {
        x = x * 2;
    }
}
```

When I run the program I get 4 as output. Will the output of the above program always be 4?

Comment: The text of mine has this in exercise but not a homework.

Answer (score 4):

It will NOT always be 4.

If the Foo run() method executes before the main thread runs fun(), it will be 9.

If the Foo run() method executes whilst main is running fun(), it will be 8.

If main() completes before Foo starts, it will be 4

Comment: Cool. thanks. Can you please explain the "8 as output" part ?

Comment: I got it. If the x = x * 2 happens after x = 5 but before the print. Am I right ?

Comment: Its worth noting that because the thread is started in the constructor, the thread could see `x` as 5, 2, or 0 (or 4 is started after fun() has started)

Comment: Peter, can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I don't believe Peter is correct. The object instantiator will set `x` to 2 and that is guaranteed thread safe by the JVM. The constructor is then invoked and sets `x` to 5. Only after it is set to 5 are any threads started. Your possible answers are thus: (5*2)-1=9; (5-1)*2=8 and (5-1)=4.

Comment: If `run` reads `x` before the first line of `fun` and writes its double back to `x` between the two lines of `fun`, then the output would be 5*2 = 10.

Comment: I agree with Paŭlo Ebermann - I had not considered that one :-) Thanks Paŭlo!

Answer (score 2):

No, not always. Because in ctor you calling `start()` method, there's race condition between call to `fun` from main thread and `run` which will change value of `x` from `Thread.start`.

But, actually, without presence of proper synchronization there no guarantees on what output will be, irrelevant to the order in which `fun` and `run` will be called. Because synchronization ensures *visibility* of changes to threads, output can be 4 even if `run` will finish before `fun` gets called.

Comment: Thanks your sir. This site is so fast :)

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are learning multi-threading, you must know that you can never predict the sequence of execution of different threads.

This is a very simple program where the main thread will almost always finish first - but important thing to remember is you can never be sure in complex multi-threaded scenarios. In fact, you chose mult-threaded approach mostly in scenarios when one thread isn't dependent on execution of another.

btw try changing constructor this way:

```
Foo () {
        x = 5;
        start();
        Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
    }
```

you may get different result.

Answer (score 0):

[Simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541477/java-thread-question/5541526#5541526) is correct with a caveat. Java has some caching of variable values. If a variable is not set as volatile or if you don't use an atomic value, you may get the cached value instead of the most recent value.

Answer (score -2):

yes it will always be 4. i see no reason for it not to be `4`

you only run `fun()` and never `run()`

read [java Thread man](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Comment: but the constructor is calling start which calls run.

Comment: there is nothing special to be done to instantiate a `Thread`, just call `new` as with regular classes. The Javadoc you cite shows an example to this as well.